# Is it ok to use NavigatorIOS multiple times in the app?

Tags: react-native

For example I have a TabBarIOS with 3 items and I want to use in each of these tabs NavigatorIOS.

Would this be an overload?

I initially wanted to use one NavigatorIOS that TabBarIOS would control, but that seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just wrap the navigators in each Tab Bar, and initialize each one with the initial route, and you should be good to go. We're using three navigator components and have not run into any issues yet. Here is a slimmed down version of my setup:

```
<TabBarIOS>
  <TabBarIOS.Item>
      <NavigatorComponent1 />
  </TabBarIOS.Item>
  <TabBarIOS.Item>
      <NavigatorComponent2 />
  </TabBarIOS.Item>      
</TabBarIOS>
```

Comment: great, thanks for the reply, I will do that tomorrow!